# Why is my ELSE statement covered even without a value?

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
       // triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;
       // triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
// triggerSwitch__c triggerSwitch = TriggerSwitch__c.getOrgDefaults();
      //  triggerSwitch.Contact_Trigger__c = true;
      //  insert triggerSwitch;

        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IF` statement, shown below, is not correct.

```
if ((answerOne != '' || answerOne != null) && (answerTwo != '' || answerTwo != null))
```

If you use the values below as an example you will see your problem:

**answerOne** = null

**answerTwo** = ''

The statement will be evaluated as:

```
if ((true || false) && (false || true))
```

which is the same as `if (true)`. No matter what values you pass in for answerOne or answerTwo that if statement will always evaluate to true

If you want the IF block of code to execute when both answerOne and answerTwo are set then you should be using:

```
if ((answerOne != '' && answerOne != null) && (answerTwo != '' && answerTwo != null))
```

If you want the IF block of code to execute when either answerOne or answerTwo are set then you should be using:

```
if ((answerOne != '' && answerOne != null) || (answerTwo != '' && answerTwo != null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below,It will cover both If as well as else

```
private static testMethod void Boset() {

  GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller controller = new  GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller();

  Test.startTest();

  //To cover IF
  controller.answerTwo= '';
  controller.answerOne= '';
  system.debug('AnswerOne' + controller.AnswerOne); 
  system.debug('AnswerTwo' + controller.AnswerTwo);
  controller.forgotPassword();

  //To Cover else
  controller.answerTwo= null;
  controller.answerOne= null;
  system.debug('AnswerOne' + controller.AnswerOne); 
  system.debug('AnswerTwo' + controller.AnswerTwo);
  controller.forgotPassword();

  Test.stopTest();
}
```

Kindly Optimize your method as below,

```
public PageReference forgotPassword() 
    PageReference pr;

    //code optimization
    if(answerTwo !=null){
      answerTwo = answerTwo.toLowerCase();}
    if(answerOne !=null){
      answerOne = answerOne.toLowerCase();}

    if ((answerOne != '' || answerOne != null) && (answerTwo != '' || answerTwo != null)) {
        if (firstAnswer != answerOne || secondAnswer != answerTwo) {
            answerError = Label.GHI_Portal_AnswerError;
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('un', userName);
        } else {
            Boolean success = Site.forgotPassword(userName);
            if (success) {
                pr = Page.GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Step3;
                pr.setRedirect(true);
                //pr.getParameters().put('un', userNameReset);

                return pr;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (String.isBlank(answerOne)) {
            questionError1 = Label.GHI_Portal_AnswerRequiredError;
            answerError ='';
        }
        if (String.isBlank(answerTwo)) {
            questionError2 = Label.GHI_Portal_AnswerRequiredError;
            answerError ='';
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: if ((answerOne != '' || answerOne != null) && (answerTwo != '' || answerTwo != null)) {
        if (firstAnswer != answerOne || secondAnswer != answerTwo) {
this line always been covered

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object -- Error on which line?

Comment: You will have to optimize your code. I am updating the same above. Please update accordingly and let me know